# destroyer by arguments in javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm trying to use filter to remove the element in an array, for example:

```
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);    // [1,1]
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3)  // should return [1, 5, 1]

function destroyer(arr) {
  checker = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1, arguments.length);
  arr.filter(desFilter);

  function desFilter(value) {
    console.log(checker, value, checker.indexOf(value) >= 0);
    return checker.indexOf(value) >= 0;
  }
  console.log(arr);
  return arr;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3); // it would return [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

codepen: http://codepen.io/dotku/pen/GqJOjZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it this way:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  checker = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1, arguments.length);
  arr = arr.filter(desFilter); // Change here

  function desFilter(value) {
    console.log(checker, value, checker.indexOf(value) >= 0);
    return checker.indexOf(value) >= 0;
  }
  console.log(arr);
  return arr;
}
```

**Reason**

The function `arr.filter()` doesn't change the original array, but it returns the replaced array. So you need to return that in your return function. In the above code, I am replacing `arr` with `arr.filter`'s result.

Answer (score 0):

I found it! `arr.filter` won't change `arr` object.

Comment: Yes, it returns a new object. You need to use `arr = arr.filter` kind of statement.

Answer (score 0):

I see you found your solution, but I am putting this here to show how to more properly write your code. Specifically, try not to define functions inside of other functions if you can help it. Also, your logic was backwards in your desFilter function:

```
function desFilter(checker, value) {
    return checker.indexOf(value) === -1;
}
function destroyer(arr) {
    checker = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1, arguments.length);
    return arr.filter(desFilter.bind(checker));
}
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```